Error while connecting Flink application with oracle for CDC
`
`Uncaught exception in the SplitEnumerator for Source Source: database Source while handling operator event RequestSplitEvent (host='') from subtask 0 (#5). Triggering job failover.
`org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Read the redoLog offset error
    at `com.ververica.cdc.connectors.oracle.source.OracleDialect.displayCurrentOffset(OracleDialect.java:66)`
    at com.ververica.cdc.connectors.oracle.source.OracleDialect.displayCurrentOffset(OracleDialect.java:50)
    at com.ververica.cdc.conne
ctors.base.source.assigner.StreamSplitAssigner.createStreamSplit(StreamSplitAssigner.java:137)
    at `com.ververica.cdc.connectors.base.source.assigner.StreamSplitAssigner.getNext(StreamSplitAssigner.java:86)`
    at com.ververica.cdc.connectors.base.source.enumerator.IncrementalSourceEnumerator.assignSplits(IncrementalSourceEnumerator.java:174)
    at com.ververica.cdc.connectors.base.source.enumerator.IncrementalSourceEnumerator.handleSplitRequest(IncrementalSourceEnumerator.java:97)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinator.handleRequestSplitEvent(SourceCoordinator.java:568)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinator.lambda$handleEventFromOperator$3(SourceCoordinator.java:295)`
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinator.lambda$runInEventLoop$10(SourceCoordinator.java:469)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve Oracle database version
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.resolveOracleDatabaseVersion(OracleConnection.java:190)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:100)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:87)
    at com.ververica.cdc.connectors.oracle.source.utils.OracleConnectionUtils.createOracleConnection(OracleConnectionUtils.java:60)
    at com.ververica.cdc.connectors.oracle.source.OracleDialect.openJdbcConnection(OracleDialect.java:82)
    at com.ververica.cdc.connectors.oracle.source.OracleDialect.displayCurrentOffset(OracleDialect.java:63)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:854)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.lambda$patternBasedFactory$0(JdbcConnection.java:192)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection$ConnectionFactoryDecorator.connect(JdbcConnection.java:129)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:888)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:883)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.queryAndMap(JdbcConnection.java:636)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.queryAndMap(JdbcConnection.java:510)
    at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.resolveOracleDatabaseVersion(OracleConnection.java:155)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:571)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:548)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:682)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:309)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1596)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:588)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection refused: connect, socket connect lapse 2024 ms. /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 1521 0 1 true
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:233)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:174)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:510)
    ... 39 more
``Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:459)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:451)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:646)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.connect(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:99)
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:77)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:192)
    ... 41 more`

I am trying to connect with oracle database to capture change in data and want to sink them in small tables. I am using Flink to achieve this as it is continuous changes needs to be capture.
I am relatively new to flink and cdc using belezium and have no clue why error is occuring.I am using OracleIncrementSource class to capture changes. Any help is greatly appreacited`
